# Eloquent model with JSON column 'UNION ALL SELECT' SQL syntax error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When running this code:

```php
App\ExampleJson::create(["name" => "example"]);
```

On this model:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ExampleJson extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        "name",
        "jsontest",
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        "jsontest" => "array",
    ];

    protected $attributes = [
        "jsontest" => [],
    ];
}
```

Created with this migration:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateExampleJsonsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('example_jsons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string("name");
            $table->json("jsontest")->default("{}");
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('example_jsons');
    }
}
```

It gives me the following exception:

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near ")": syntax error (SQL: insert into "example_jsons" () select  union all select )'`

I'm using SQLite for my database and Laravel 5.4.

What causes this and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the `$attributes` seems to be processed before the casts to array are made, changing it to a JSON string seems to fix it:

```php
protected $attributes = [
    "jsontest" => "{}",
];
```

I'm not entirely sure this is what's happening but I'm no longer getting an error and the data is correctly saved to the database.